# react native maps markers android error while updating property 'coordinate'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to get multiple markers via json.

The error it throws is:
Error while updating property 'coordinate' of a view managed by: AIRMapMarker

null

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
updateViewProp
    ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:92

[Image of the error attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA6ut.png)

Details:

React Native Version: 0.55.1
React Native Maps: 0.16.4
Android compileSdkVersion 28

Here is my elements object which I am passing in state:

```
      `var elements = responseJson.listings.map(function(e) {
        return {
          id: e.id,
          latlng: {
            latitude: e.latitude,
            longitude: e.longitude,
          }
        }
       });`
```

Here is where I am mapping the markers:

```
{elements.map((marker, index) => {

      return (
        <MapView.Marker
        key={marker.id}
        coordinate={marker.latlng}
        />
      );

    })}
```

This works in ios perfectly, but android throws this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused from the data you are mapping. In my case I was mapping a marker like you did, and I missed one of the object in my data was empty latitude. So it throwed the same error. 
Hope you found out what was wrong.